# React native doesn't show {this.state.age} in Text

Tags: ios, react-native, this

React native won't display any of my States in  or . But they're working with functions.

That is in my Code:

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Image,
  Text, //Important
  PanResponder,
  Animated,
  Dimensions,
  Button,
  Slider,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Modal, // Important    
} from 'react-native'
```

My Constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {ModalMenu: false};
    this.state = {ModalKunst: false};
    this.state = {ModalArtwork: false};
    this.state = { viewRef: null };
    this.state = { age: 150 };
    this.state = { farbe: 'black'};
    this.state = {ModalPrice: false};

    this.state = {
       TextInputName: '',
       TextInputEmail: '', 
    }
    this.state = { 
      TextInputName2: '',
      TextInputEmail2: ''
    } 
}
```

To display the State:

```
  render() {
    const {birthday, name, bio, id, id2} = this.props.profile
    const profileAge = this.calcAge(birthday)
    var fbImage = require('./img/bild12.jpg')

    const rotateCard = this.pan.x.interpolate({
      inputRange: [-200, 0, 200],
      outputRange: ['10deg', '0deg', '-10deg'],
    })
    const animatedStyle = {
      transform: [
        {translateX: this.pan.x},
        {translateY: this.pan.y},
        {rotate: rotateCard},
      ]
    }    
     return (    
        <View><Text>{this.state.age}</Text></View>
     );
  }}
```

But its showing nothing :(
I also don't get an error
Would be very nice if someone could help me out with that.
I updated all the render code

Comment: can you show your full code

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: yapz.. maybe you must to show full code. so we know your problem..

Comment: I updated it, sorry.

Comment: I also updated the full render!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the constructor please do all your initialization at once. Every this.state = {} statement is overriding the previous this.state

replace your constructor with following code.

```
this.state = {
    ModalMenu: false,
    ModalKunst: false,
    viewRef: null,
    age: 150,
    farbe: 'black',
    ModalPrice: false
};
```

Comment: I have that,  its still not working, I don't get an error or something, its just showing blank.

Comment: It is better to share the whole component code here for understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Heres a sample code try this..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
   constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {age: '25'};
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <View >
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
           {this.state.age}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  paragraph: {
    margin: 44,
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#34495e',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your render method doesn't return anything. Add **return** inside 
**render** method.

**change this:**

```
render() {
 *not important*
}
```

**to:**

```
render() {
  return (
   <View><Text>{this.state.age}</Text></View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you are continually overriding your state, I've tidied your code up a bit below, here are some points to note about what I've done...

1. You need to import React from 'react' to utilise 'Component' as your class needs to extend from this.
2. You need to use a class as you have state
3. You can import an image like I've done below with fbImage
4. It's good habit to have say what is your exported default in each component you make.
5. You don't need to call constructor and super, just simply doing state = {} will do this for you
6. Place all your state within one state object, don't keep recalling state
7. Think about your general code formatting (in terms of how it looks) easier code to read will help you identify errors more easily!

   ```
   import React from 'react'
   import {
     StyleSheet,
     View,
     Image,
     Text, //Important
     PanResponder,
     Animated,
     Dimensions,
     Button,
     Slider,
     TouchableWithoutFeedback,
     Alert,
     TouchableOpacity,
     TouchableHighlight,
     Modal, // Important    
   } from 'react-native'

   import fbImage from './img/bild12.jpg'

   export default class App extends React.Component {
       state = {
       age: 150,
       farbe: 'black',
       ModalArtwork: false,
       ModalKunst: false,
       ModalMenu: false,
       ModalPrice: false,
       TextInputName: '',
       TextInputEmail: '',
       TextInputName2: '',
       TextInputEmail2: '',
       viewRef: null,
   }

       render() {

           const {birthday, name, bio, id, id2} = this.props.profile
           const profileAge = this.calcAge(birthday)

           const rotateCard = this.pan.x.interpolate(
               {
                   inputRange: [-200, 0, 200],
                   outputRange: ['10deg', '0deg', '-10deg'],
               }
           )

           const animatedStyle = {
               transform: [
                   {translateX: this.pan.x},
                   {translateY: this.pan.y},
                   {rotate: rotateCard},
               ]
           }   

        return (    
           <View>
               <Text>
                   {this.state.age}
               </Text>
           </View>
        )

     }

   }
   ```